# error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Recipe' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

I'm trying to sort a vector that contains an int and a string in each element. It is a vector of class type called vector recipes. Getting the above error, here's my code:

In my Recipe.h file

```
struct Recipe {
public:
    string get_cname() const
    {
        return chef_name;
    }
private:
    int recipe_id;
    string chef_name;
```

In my Menu.cpp file

```
void Menu::show() const {
    sort(recipes.begin(), recipes.end(), Sort_by_cname());
}
```

In my Menu.h file

```
#include <vector>
#include "Recipe.h"
using namespace std;

struct Sort_by_cname 
{
    bool operator()(const Recipe& a, const Recipe& b)
    {
        return a.get_cname() < b.get_cname();
    }
};

class Menu {
public: 
    void show() const;
private
    vector<Recipe> recipes;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the line on which you get that error...

Comment: Are you sure you want to sort on the string value and not the recipe id?

Comment: I added a [tag:c++] tag; it should get this question more attention.

Comment: Have you considered using a set instead of a vector?  That way it's sorted by default, and you don't have to make it mutable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Menu::show()` is declared `const`, so inside of it `Menu::recipes` is considered to have been declared as `std::vector<Recipe> const`.

Obviously, sorting a `std::vector<>` mutates it, so `Menu::show()` must not be `const` (or `Menu::recipes` must be `mutable`, but this seems semantically incorrect in this case).

Comment: That actually makes sense and explains the assignment compiler error.

Comment: Holy- . I have been struggling with this more than an hour and thought it has something to do with my copy constructor but turns out I was sorting my vector that was received as const parameter in a function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have marked your show method as `const` which isn't true because it is changing the recipes vector.  When I compile the code you have outlined with gnu gcc 4.2.1 the error is specific to disqualifying the const qualifier, not the error you've posted.

You could mark your vector with the keyword `mutable` but I suspect that isn't what you really want? By marking the vector mutable it ignores the constness the compiler would normally enforce within `Menu::show() const` of the vector and it gets changed everytime Menu::show() is called.  If you really want to use the vector, and not an ordered set like others have suggested, you could add a dirty state flag to let your program know when it should resort, or not.

The following code I have compiles by changing the vector to mutable to show you the difference, but I still recommend that you don't use sort from with a const show method.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct Recipe {
public:
  string get_cname() const
  {
    return chef_name;
  }
private:
  int recipe_id;
  string chef_name;
};

class Menu {
public:
  void show() const;
private:
  mutable vector<Recipe> recipes;
};

struct Sort_by_cname
{
  bool operator()(const Recipe& a, const Recipe& b)
  {
    return a.get_cname() < b.get_cname();
  }
};

void Menu::show() const {
  sort(recipes.begin(), recipes.end(), Sort_by_cname());
}
```

Comment: The comparator __should__ take arguments by `const&` (and its `operator()` should itself be `const`); the problem is that his `vector<Recipe>` is `const`.

Comment: vector<Recipe> is not marked const, it only has const semantics because the method show() is marked const.  That is why I suggested the use of the mutable keyword to qualify the vector type.

Comment: I understand that, I only meant that the net effect is the same.