# No '==' operator found which takes a left-hand operand of const Type

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I was refactoring some of my code to use a structure instead of a single object.

As a result of this change I needed to add in the  operator for '==' so my existing vector involving functions could correctly evaluate my objects stored in the vectors.

```
class IdentifyingClass; //forward declare class     
Class ReturnData
{
public:
  IdentifyingClass* value;
  float  some_trivial_additional_data;

  bool operator==(const ReturnData& query_obj)
  {
    return value == query_obj.value;
  }

  bool operator==(const IdentifyingClass* query_obj)
  {
    return value == query_obj;
  }
}
```

All my existing code that relied on this class was functioning correctly. I thought it was an open and shut refactor.

Then I had use of it in a different place in a different solution in a specific edge case that used this class type. I was attempting to use this

```
IdentifyingClass* object;
const std::vector<ReturnData>& data_vector = GetDataFromPlace();
if(std::find(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), object) != data_vector.end()))
{
  //do special action;
}
```

Now I was generating a vector '==' comparison error telling me I didn't have a left-hand '==' operand of "const ReturnData".

Comment: No I just thought providing context on what I was doing and then the solution was acceptable. This was a question and answer post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not the real question

Comment: Okay then. I apologise if I accidentally misused stack overflow. I was just attempting to contribute.

Comment: @Jakey113G Might as well comment -- why would you want something as counterintuitive as an operator == that takes a pointer?  What if I want to compare pointer values for equality, like maybe in an overloaded assignment operator?  When a C++ programmer sees a pointer being compared, it is expecting that pointers are being compared.  If they want an object to be compared, then the user should know to dereference the pointer and use that.  Introducing an overloaded operator == that takes a pointer increases the risk of compilation errors, or worse, strange events happening at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a few things while looking with bafflement as to why the operator wasn't const when clearly my parameters were handling const.

It got to the point where I changed my above code to use std::find_if and used a lambda as my predicate to resolve the code to the functionality I wanted.

The real issue was my operators were not marked const:

```
bool operator==(const ReturnData& query_obj) const
{
  return value == query_obj.value;
}

bool operator==(const IdentifyingClass* query_obj) const
{
  return value == query_obj;
}
```

The reason I have made this rather trivial issue into a stack overflow post is that other posts I have found similar to this only highlight other issues with those posts and not this specific case, which did take a little while to spot.

Top related posts of my issue:

[Vector is of const objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800646/error-c2678-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-left-hand-operand-of-t)

[Typedef and namespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800646/error-c2678-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-left-hand-operand-of-t)

Comment: To answer you above you can submit things as question and answer. I thought it was a valid contribution. I also at the end of my answer said why I made it. I will delete this post now as you seem to have made it clear to me to not ever submit a question answer post.